# PHP artisan doesn't work after updating composer

Tags: php, laravel

update php 7.1 -> 7.3 and composer 1.*-> 2

created a new Laravel project with `laravel new`

added database when tried running `php artisan migrate` got error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /home/pratik/gitlab/blog/bootstrap/app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/pratik/gitlab/blog/artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/pratik/gitlab/blog/bootstrap/app.php on line 14
```

Comment: looks like you need to run `composer install`

Comment: already tried it

Comment: have you updated the laravel installer as well e.g. using `composer global update laravel/installer` ? What version of the installer are you on?

Comment: I did update laravel installer and current version is `Composer version 2.0.6` and `"laravel/installer": "^4.1"` in /.config/composer/composer.json

Answer (score -1):

I had to install missing extensions

```
sudo apt install php7.3-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php7.3-xml
```

and than `composer update` and it was solved.